# Webview - Starting a service through a JS interface. Wrong context?

Tags: javascript, android, service, webview, android-context

This is my first question here, but I'm a constant reader of the awesome advice.  My issue is this - I have a HTML app inside of a WebView with all local files.  It works fine.  The problem arises when I try to invoke a service via a JS interface.  I have the JS interface working correctly and can be successful with a Toast, but the app crashes when I try startService(intent).  The same startService works fine from the main java file.  I think the issue is with the context, but I'm not sure.  The error shown is:

```
04-25 21:09:55.923: W/dalvikvm(1516): threadid=9: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
04-25 21:10:20.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1516): FATAL EXCEPTION: WebViewCoreThread
04-25 21:10:20.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1516): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 21:10:20.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1516):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:336)
04-25 21:10:20.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1516):     at com.tour.giants.JavaScriptInterface.playMedia(JavaScriptInterface.java:40)
04-25 21:10:20.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1516):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
04-25 21:10:20.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1516):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
04-25 21:10:20.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1516):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$3300(WebViewCore.java:54)
04-25 21:10:20.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1516):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1159)
04-25 21:10:20.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1516):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 21:10:20.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1516):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-25 21:10:20.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1516):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:630)
04-25 21:10:20.033: E/AndroidRuntime(1516):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
04-25 21:10:20.103: I/Process(1516): Sending signal. PID: 1516 SIG: 9
```

Here is the offending code:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface extends Activity{
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    public void playMedia(String mediaUrl) {

            //THIS WORKS!
        Toast.makeText(mContext, mediaUrl, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MyService.class);

        // If this is AUDIO, play the audio in the background
        if(mediaUrl.endsWith(".mp3")){
            intent.putExtra("music_url", mediaUrl);
                    //THIS CRASHES!
            startService(intent);
        } 
    }
}
```

Finally, I have successfully launched this service from WebView by intercepting a link using almost identical code.

```
// Create Webview client to override browser rendering url and disable address bar
private class GWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // HTML5 Audio and Video give very mixed results.  Let Android handle media player

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class);

        // If this is AUDIO, play the audio in the background
        else if(url.endsWith(".mp3")){   
            intent.putExtra("music_url", url);
            startService(intent);
        } 
        // This isn't a video or audio file - load normally
        else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

I have tried using different contexts such as `getBaseContext()` and `getApplicationContext()` etc...

Comment: I had the JavaScriptInterface extend Activity because startService() would have an error without that.  I declared in in the manifest under 
<application>
...
<activity android:name=".JavaScriptInterface"></activity>
</application>

Comment: It doesn't reach the service, verified from log statements.